# how to show the user input values in modal popup using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML table. Assume that one of the rows of table has three different user inputs(text, checkboxes, and dropdown). My aim is to show the values selected in user inputs row along with other table rows in a bootstrap modal popup window. Sharing the code for reference. Please check and help. Attaching the output snaps for results what i am getting

```js
function addTable() {
  var modalbody = document.querySelector('.modal-body');
  if (modalbody.childElementCount <= 1) {
    var tableDiv = document.getElementById("myTableBody");
    var table = document.createElement('TABLE');
    var oldtble = document.getElementById('table1');
    table.border = '1';
    var tableBody = document.createElement('TBODY');
    table.appendChild(tableBody);
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      var tr = document.createElement('TR');
      tr.style.border = 'solid 2px black';
      tr.style.padding = '5px';
      tableBody.appendChild(tr);
      for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        var td = document.createElement('TD');
        td.width = '100px';
        td.style.border = 'solid 2px black';
        td.style.padding = '5px';
        td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(oldtble.rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML));
        tr.appendChild(td);
      }
    }
  }
  tableDiv.appendChild(table);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <table class="table table-hover" id="table1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">First</th>
        <th scope="col">Last</th>
        <th scope="col">Handle</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">1</th>
        <td>Mark</td>
        <td>Otto</td>
        <td>@mdo</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">2</th>
        <td>Jacob</td>
        <td>Thornton</td>
        <td>@fat</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">3</th>
        <td>Larry the Bird</td>
        <td>You are mine</td>
        <td>@twitter</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <th scope="row">4</th>
        <td>
          <select name="myOptions" id="myOptions">
            <option value="">Select one from below</option>
            <option value="A">A</option>
            <option value="B">B</option>
            <option value="C">C</option>
            <option value="D">D</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="myText" id="myTextinput">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" id="option1">Option 1<br>
          <input type="checkbox" id="option2">Option 2<br>
          <input type="checkbox" id="option3">Option 3<br>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <!-- Button trigger modal -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" id="button1" onclick="addTable();">
    Launch demo modal
  </button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" id="myTableBody">
          <h5 class="lead">Make some coding to display that table</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="table_script.js"></script>

</html>
```

[image: HTML5 Table with one row having user inputs]
[image: Table i am getting without user inputs]

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: @mplungjan, most likely the OP wants to display the data selected in the table in a pop-up window

Comment: The last row is not showing in modal popup window..

Answer (score 1):

You haven't said what your issue is, but if it is that it is not showing the last (user input) row in your modal, <4 will only do 4 rows (0,1,2,3), not the 5th row with your desired inputs.  Try <=4 or <5.

Comment: Yes the last row is not showing in yhe bootstrap modal... i even tried using jquery but it didnt showed up any... plse help

Comment: like I said, your first problem is that you need to iterate over 5 rows to print #4, so change to "for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++)."

Answer (score 1):

```js
function addTable() {
  $('#myTableBody table').remove();
  var modalbody = document.querySelector('.modal-body');
  if (modalbody.childElementCount <= 1) {
    var tableDiv = document.getElementById("myTableBody");
    var table = document.createElement('TABLE');
    var oldtble = document.getElementById('table1');
    table.border = '1';
    var tableBody = document.createElement('TBODY');
    table.appendChild(tableBody);
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      var tr = document.createElement('TR');
      tr.style.border = 'solid 2px black';
      tr.style.padding = '5px';
      tableBody.appendChild(tr);
      
      if(i == 4){
        for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
          var val = "";
          var td = document.createElement('TD');
          td.width = '100px';
          td.style.border = 'solid 2px black';
          td.style.padding = '5px';
          
          if(j == 0){
            val = oldtble.rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML;
          }
          else if(j == 1){
            var gettd = oldtble.rows[i].cells[j];
            var finddom = $(gettd).find("#myOptions");
            val = $(finddom).attr("selected",  "selected").val();
          }
          else if(j == 2){
            var gettd = oldtble.rows[i].cells[j];
            var finddom = $(gettd).find("#myTextinput");
            val = $(finddom).val();
          }
          else if(j == 3){
            var gettd = oldtble.rows[i].cells[j];
            var finddom = $(gettd).find(".option1");
            $(finddom).each(function () {
              if($(this).is(':checked'))
              {
                val += $(this).attr('val');
              }
            });
          }
          
          td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(val));
          tr.appendChild(td);
        }
      }
      else{
        for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
          var td = document.createElement('TD');
          td.width = '100px';
          td.style.border = 'solid 2px black';
          td.style.padding = '5px';
          td.appendChild(document.createTextNode( oldtble.rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML));
          tr.appendChild(td);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  tableDiv.appendChild(table);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <table class="table table-hover" id="table1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">First</th>
        <th scope="col">Last</th>
        <th scope="col">Handle</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">1</th>
        <td>Mark</td>
        <td>Otto</td>
        <td>@mdo</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">2</th>
        <td>Jacob</td>
        <td>Thornton</td>
        <td>@fat</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">3</th>
        <td>Larry the Bird</td>
        <td>You are mine</td>
        <td>@twitter</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <th scope="row">4</th>
        <td>
          <select name="myOptions" id="myOptions">
            <option value="">Select one from below</option>
            <option value="A">A</option>
            <option value="B">B</option>
            <option value="C">C</option>
            <option value="D">D</option>
          </select>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="myText" id="myTextinput">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" class="option1" val="Option 1">Option 1<br>
          <input type="checkbox" class="option1"  val="Option 2">Option 2<br>
          <input type="checkbox" class="option1"  val="Option 3">Option 3<br>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <!-- Button trigger modal -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal" id="button1" onclick="addTable();">
    Launch demo modal
  </button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" id="myTableBody">
          <h5 class="lead">Make some coding to display that table</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js" integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="table_script.js"></script>

</html>
```

Note: it may seem a bit messy cause as I use your hardcode loop length. But this may be the idea you looking for. I make some changes in the HTML checkboxes and in the javascript function.

Comment: thank you so much, bro! This really helps me a lot and understood how for and if loops work typically in real case example in javascript. I wonder how my life would be if there is no website called StackOverflow.

Comment: But @nayem_43 bro, for checkbox options, if I select one checkbox, I am able to see the checked value in the popup window. but if I select two, I am seeing only one in the modal popup. can u guide me on how to resolve this??

Comment: @Shanmuk Eswar bro, it's very simple. just modify the line "val = $(this).attr('val');" to this "val += $(this).attr('val');". Just put a plus symbol before equal sign. It will add other values to "val" if there is more than on checkbox selected.

Comment: bro, thank you. I have one more question and wanna ask you if you dont get angry :).. I am giving the input values and clicking on button and able to see the given values in inputs in modal popup window which is expected...


but after closing the popup window, and modifying values in inputs and clicking again the button, i am seeing older values instead of modified one. so can u help me here???

Comment: @Shanmuk Eswar bro, why I will get angry! This is the community we looking for. Helping each other. So you can ask me questions. Of course, I will try to help you as much as I can.

Comment: @Shanmuk Eswar bro, I edited the code snippet and add a new line "$('#myTableBody table').remove();" at the starting of addTable function. This will remove the previously added table and updated the new one with new modified data. If we don't do that then "modalbody.childElementCount" will return 2 and if condition doesn't allow us to insert a new table. Hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: bro, I am trying another functionality here. I have another dropdown that is outside the table. Now when the user selects the value, it should be displayed in the modal popup header title. tried below js but didnt worked.
var modalHeader = document.querySelector('.modal-header');
 if (modalHeader.childElementCount <= 1) {
  var e = $('.lead').find('#shifts'); (shifts is the id of outside dropdown)
  val = $(e).attr("selected", "selected").val();
  val = $('.modal-title').find('#exampleModalLabel').innerHTML;
 }

Comment: just add this 2 line  before this line "tableDiv.appendChild(table);" (last line of the function)
            var option = $('#shifts :selected').text();
            $('#exampleModalLabel').text(option); 
Here i take the text. It will take the selected option's text not value. If you want value than use this
            var option = $('#shifts :selected').val();

Comment: bro, thank you. now i want to add little complxity here. That is displaying current date. I have js code snippet for this. just want to confirm how i can show it in modal-title popup window after the dropdown value.. like say <dropdownvalue>11-03-2021 as in example. below is the code
var option = $('#shifts :selected').text();
var d = new Date();
let month = d.getMonth();
let year = d.getFullYear();
let today = d.getDate();
let currentDate = `{$today}-{$month}-{$year}`;
option += currentDate;

correct my above code if it is wrong..

Comment: bro, now in that table i have a row with colspan as 2 and another row with rowspan as 2. how i can display those rows in modal popup using js. adding the code in next comment...

Comment: #colspan:
if (1==5) {
 for (var j=0; j<4; j++) {
  var val = "";
  var td = document.createElement('TD');
  td.width = '100px';
  td.style.border = 'solid 2px black';
  td.style.padding = '5px';
  if (j==0) {
   val = oldtble.rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML;
  } else if {j==1) {
   $('#myCol').attr('colspan',2);
   val = oldtble.rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML;
  } else if (j==3) {
   val = oldtble.rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML;
  }
 }
 td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(val));
 tr.appendChild(td);

Comment: #rowspan:
if (i==6) {
 for (var j=0; j<4; j++) {
   var val = "";
   var td = document.createElement('TD');
   td.width = '100px';
   td.style.border = 'solid 2px black';
   td.style.padding = '5px';
   if (j==0) {
    $('#myRow').attr('rowspan',2);
    val = oldtble.rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML;
   } else if(j==1 || j==2 || j=3) {
    val = oldtble.rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML;
   }
 }
}